# fluent NHibernate many to many creates additional table

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have two tables "recall" and "service" and I need many to many between them.
I use fluent NHibernate mapping but it creates additional table with name "servicetorecall"

```
           public class Recall : BaseDomain
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string PersonPosition { get; set; }
    public virtual string RecallText { get; set; }


    private ICollection<Service> _services = new List<Service>();
    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services
    {
        get { return _services; }
        set { _services = value; }
    } 
}

    public class Service : BaseDomain
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual string ImgPath { get; set; }
    public virtual string ShortContent { get; set; }
    public virtual string Content { get; set; }
    public virtual bool ServiceIsVisible { get; set; }

    ICollection<Recall> _recalls = new List<Recall>();
    public virtual ICollection<Recall> Recalls
    {
        get { return _recalls; }
        set { _recalls = value; }
    } 
}
```

Mappings :

```
 class RecallMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Recall>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Recall> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Cache.ReadWrite();
        mapping.HasManyToMany(q => q.Services).Table(MappingNames.RECALLS_RELATIONS)
            .ParentKeyColumn(MappingNames.RECALL_ID)
            .ChildKeyColumn(MappingNames.SERVICE_ID).Inverse().Cascade.All();

    }
}


public class ServiceMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Service>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Service> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Cache.ReadWrite();
        mapping.HasManyToMany(q => q.Recalls).Table(MappingNames.RECALLS_RELATIONS)                  .ParentKeyColumn(MappingNames.SERVICE_ID).ChildKeyColumn(MappingNames.RECALL_ID)
               .Inverse().Cascade.All();

    }
}
```

I tried to change cascades but this didn't help. Also I did the same with other entities and it works correctly what type of magic is it?

Answer (score 1):

How do you define "correct", what do you want to achieve? 
I never heard of any clean solution for many to many relations which **doesn't** use pivot table.

---

[quick glimpse at your mappings]: only one of the "ManyToMany" should be Inverse